# Can not open H2Spatial Database anywhere

Tags: java, h2

I have a H2 database that use h2spatial functions. 
but when i try open it , it cause an error like this :

```
Database driver not found
See in the Help for how to add drivers

Class "org.h2gis.h2spatial.internal.function.spatial.properties.ST_GeometryTypeCode" not found; SQL statement:
CREATE DOMAIN MULTIPOINT AS GEOMETRY(4) CHECK (PUBLIC.ST_GEOMETRYTYPECODE(VALUE) = 4) [90086-196] 90086/90086
```

how can i solve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the version 1.2.3 of H2GIS:

https://github.com/orbisgis/h2gis/releases/download/v1.2.3/h2-dist-1.2.3-bin.zip

The package org.h2gis.h2spatial has been dropped since v1.3.X